Bind Mount and File Permissions Issues Docker Compose Across Mac/Windows Hosts
I'm running into a headscratcher. I'm working on a team of developers where we use both Mac and Windows machines. We're using Docker Compose to run our application locally for development purposes (PHP Apache and MySQL containers with Docker Compose). One of the powerful features of this that we're taking advantage of is using bind mounts to edit files in the Apache container and see the changes reflect live - it makes developing quite a bit easier.
On the Mac machines, we have no problems. On the Windows machines, it seems like we're getting the Windows carriage returns in all of our files, even freshly cloned from GitHub. We "fixed" that temporarily by switching Line Separators to Unix/Mac style in PHPStorm across all of our files. It's not an elegant solution, and that is one problem I'd like help with.
The second issue with the Windows machines that we're running into is that all of the files in the bind mount are having incorrect permissions applied to them, which is causing additional issues. For example, we bind mount a mysql config file in our docker-compose.yml to apply custom settings to the MySQL server at startup. That had incorrect permissions applied to it, which led me to creating a separate Dockerfile for the MySQL container where the config file is copied into the container and then chmod'd with the correct permissions.
Short of running the Compose stack in a Linux VM on the Windows machines, what are the answers here? Is there a way to get the on-the-fly editing capabilities that we need without using bind mounts or in a way that will preserve file permissions?
If the answer involves making things more insecure in the Compose stack, that's not a problem - the Compose stack is ONLY used for local development - we're using managed databases in development/production and just using the Apache container from our Dockerfile.
Apache Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.2-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libonig-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install curl


WORKDIR /var/www/html


COPY public_html/. /var/www/html
COPY include /var/www/include
COPY vendor /var/www/vendor
COPY db /var/www/db
COPY phinx.php /var/www/phinx.php
COPY Makefile /var/www/Makefile


COPY server_files/apache/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY server_files/apache/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY server_files/apache/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
COPY server_files/apache/local.htpasswd /etc/apache2/local.htpasswd


COPY server_files/apache/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY server_files/apache/ssl.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.conf


EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
networks:
  db-net:

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: ${MYSQL_HOSTNAME}
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql  
      - ./server_files/mysql:/etc/mysql/conf.d  
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - 3306
    networks:
      db-net:

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENABLE_XDEBUG: ${ENABLE_XDEBUG:-true}
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    environment:
      RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT: ${RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT}
      ENABLE_XDEBUG: ${ENABLE_XDEBUG}
      MYSQL_HOSTNAME: ${MYSQL_HOSTNAME}
      MYSQL_PORT: ${MYSQL_PORT}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER_RO: ${MYSQL_USER_RO}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_RO: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD_RO}

    volumes:
      - ./public_html/.:/var/www/html
      - ./include/:/var/www/include
      - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor
      - ./db:/var/www/db

    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      db-net:

volumes:
  mysql-data:

